# Books/resources about how to write a good Thesis introduction

Tags: thesis, writing, methodology

I would like to know if there is any reference book about this topic.

I found the "They Say/ I say" book useful to write the Thesis discussion, but feel I need some guidelines on how to tackle this other part of the Thesis.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best resource for how to write a thesis is to see other successful thesis that were written in the last 10 years, in your field, from your or other universities .

Search in Google Scholar; or check your university's library where they hold all the Ph.D. thesis done at your university.

Comment: Sure, this will be useful. However, I would like to have some general guidelines for thesis introduction writing in order to spend as less as possible time reading same good writing patterns in each thesis.